# javascript key i18n

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, key

i have a code something like this.

```
var myI18n; // json : "{"close":"بستن","locationInformation":"مشخصات جغرافیایی","yes":"بله","no":"خیر"}"
```

and i want to use in somthing like this.

```
$.modal({
    buttons: {
        myI18n.close: function(win) {

        }
    }
});
```

but i have a syntax error.
also with this method string not change.

```
var aaa = myI18n.close;
$.modal({
    buttons: {
        aaa: function(win) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: besides, `myI18n.close` is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to assign properties with dynamic names to an object is to use array syntax

```
 var myButtons = {};
 myButtons[myi18n.close] = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference variables in key names in object literal, so you need to create your object first, fill it using regular `[]` notation and then just use it in `$.modal`.

```
buttons = {}

buttons[myI18n.close] = function(win) {
   // ....
}

$.modal({
    buttons: buttons
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an object literal directly with a variable key. You'll need to separate out your code to use the array access syntax (`obj[keyname] = value`).

```
var obj = {
        buttons: {}
    };
obj.buttons[myI18n.close] = function () {...};
$.modal(obj);
```

Alternatively, you could use a module pattern:

```
$.modal({
    buttons: (function () {
        var btns = {};
        btns[myI18n.close] = function () {...};
        return btns;
    }())
});
```